# Is it correct to say "Is there a cafe there?" or is the last there unnecessary?

Tags: there-is

Is it correct to say "Is there a cafe there?" or is the last *there* at the end of the sentence unnecessary and the correct way is "Is there a cafe?"

Comment: Locative/directional _there_ is very different to existential _there_ (the French have different words) and is emphasised, so word-repeat is no problem. Is the locative 'there' necessary here? That depends on the context, but it can usually be omitted and assumed (the antecedent being obligatory anyway).

Comment: If you're asking about the existence of a cafe in some previously mentioned place then, yes, the second "there" is required where it functions as a locative preposition. (or adverb for some).

Comment: @Edwin, In French, the word “y” is used for both locative and existential “there”, although It’s true you probably wouldn’t use both meanings in the same sentence. A better example is German, which uses “gibt es ein Café?” for the existential meaning (Does it give a cafe?”)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can mean different things. The first “there” is an existential “there”; with just the first “there”, you’re asking "does a cafe exist?" The second “there” is locative; with it, the question asks "does a cafe exist in that location?"

Very often, "in that location" will be implied by context, in which case the second "there" is unnecessary.  But sometimes you need the second "there".

For example, in this conversation, you need both "there"s:

> "He told me to meet him in the cafe at the corner of Second street and Archibald."
> "Is there a cafe there?"

Comment: This isn't ELU level.

Comment: @Peter Check the order. Doesn't the second *there* address location? "Does a cafe exist in that location?"